# xslt concatenate all descendants of a type using a separator

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am using XSL to convert a HTML document to XML. How to concatenate the text in all the descendant nodes of a particular type with a separator?As an example I have a table node and it has several td nodes as descendants, how to combine the text in all those td elements?For the below input and using ',' as separator, the output should be 'value1,value2,value3,value4'

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>value2</td>
                    <td>value3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>value4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @αƞjiβ XSL style sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//td[text()]" separator=","/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(//td[text()],',')"/>
```

`string-join()` is particularly useful in [AVT's](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: This should be <xsl:value-of select="string-join(descendant::td[text()],',')"/> , to concatenate only descendant tds

Comment: @themanwhosoldtheworld - It all depends on the context. You could also use `.//td` instead of `descendant::td`.

Comment: @themanwhosoldtheworld: You do realize that `.//td` is short for `descendant-or-self::td`, right?  This answer is essentially correct and should be [**accepted**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215), as probably should some of  the answers to the other 19 questions you've asked (yet only accepted 3).